# What Terminal command would I use to launch a Java Executable?

Tags: command-line, launcher, java

I know I can just double click it and it will run, but i want something I don't need my desktop for, and can put it in the sidebar. I have a command, but creating a launcher isn't working.

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Jar, then you have to

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

else if it's a jnlp

```
javaws filename.jnlp
```

I hope that works

Comment: If it has been compiled using 'java', then you can use 'javac' to run the executable.